# Pulling my github repository and deploying it on apache

Tags: apache, git, ubuntu, github

**My Setup:**

- EC2 Instance with Ubuntu
- Apache2 installed (publishes /var/www folder)
- Git installed
- SSH Keys Set:

> $ ssh -T git@github.com
>
> Hi User! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

**My intention:**

I want to pull a specific repository on github and publish it onto apache (basically puting the files into /var/www)

**Where I am stuck:**

- Permissions of /var/www are set to root
- trying to use sudo for cloning the repo results in a denied permission (root user uses different ssh keys?)
- Where to clone my repo to? What diretory is appropriate for that?
- How to copy the files then to /var/www?

---

I am quite new to Linux, so please help me :-) Thank you

Comment: SSH uses certificates from `~/.ssh` directory, so for root user it will be `/root/.ssh` rather than `/home/<your_username>/.ssh`.

Comment: Can't you change the owner of `/var/www` to a user that will do the git stuffs? Use `chown` to change the ownership of files/directories.

Answer (score 0):

I used root's ssh key and that works!
Just created new keys by using the `sudo` command and used them with github.